# Php reading xml in post request

Tags: php, xml, xmlhttprequest, publish-subscribe

So, I have perform two steps

a) Create a some random xml file in one of the php file. 
b) Parse the same xml file in second file.

Key points are that 
php file in a) will issue a post request to php file b) with only xml as its request.

file b) will have to read the xml file using SImpleXml.

I am trying to do something for this http://blog.superfeedr.com/API/pubsubhubbub/getting-started-with-pubsubhubbub/.

I my server will be receiving notifications in form of xml from the the superfeeder. The notifications will be xml file in the request.

I am doing step a) just to confirm that my part b) is correct.

How to do this in PHP.
I tried all the $_REQUEST, $GLOBALS variable. But, not sure whats the way!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not really sure I understand what you are trying to do but try looking in to reading raw post data. Here is a blog post that talks about it a little bit.

http://www.codediesel.com/php/reading-raw-post-data-in-php/

Comment: Now comes the second paart of parsing this xml!

Also, how do I post the xml from a to b?

Comment: You can parse the xml with the SimpleXML or DOMDocument library in PHP. To post xml, you can use cURL. Here is another post that talks about using curl to post data.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871431/raw-post-using-curl-in-php

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send POST data from PHP, you could use cURL. You can't set `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` at the sending side and expect them to be set at the receiving end as well.

Have a look at this question: [Send XML over HTTPS/POST via cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238784/php4-send-xml-over-https-post-via-curl)