# how to display http_post in php?

Tags: java, php, android

I've got this http_post xml sending in my android project:

```
try {
            xml_input();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Hiba!", "Xml_input fgv hivasa");
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://users.atw.hu/festivale/xml_post.php");
        StringEntity se;
        try {
            se = new StringEntity(globalconstants.xml_out, HTTP.UTF_8);
            se.setContentType("text/xml");
            httppost.setHeader("Content-Type",
                    "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8");
            httppost.setEntity(se);

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient
                    .execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity r_entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String xmlString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);

            System.err.println("Error...." + xmlString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

- How can i display this in on my php site?
- And is this a good xml sending if i want some rules etc. sending to a server?

Comment: what exactly do you want to display?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php reading xml in post request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068875/php-reading-xml-in-post-request)

Comment: just pass your xml String in a POST Parameter , and then display it in PHP via : `$xml = $_POST['yourParameterXML']; echo $xml;`

Comment: that's what i don't understand what is the my parameter? because i do not send any parameters not like this:List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access `http_post` data using `$_POST` superglobal associative array in php. Like-

```
echo $_POST['foo'];
```

Comment: i understand that... but how do i send this 'foo' with this code?because no such line as: List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

Comment: @david Try to set content-type header to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". And send plain text to see if the data is even sent or not.

Comment: but how can i display this on the php site? because now i do not send any parameters as you said like 'foo'...

Comment: @david have you tried `print_r($_POST)`?