# is there another way to do this HTTP request in php?

Tags: php, httpwebrequest

```
function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null) {

    $request = new HttpRequest($url, HttpRequest::METH_POST);
    $request->setBody($data);
        $response = $request->send();
        return $response->getBody();

}
```

This piece of code doesn't seem to be working, and seems to crash my script. I don't know if its because I don't have the php_http module, but is there an equivalent I can use?

For instance curl? I have tried curl, but I don't know much about it, and with curl I got a "bad request" returned from the server I was trying to connect to with a 400 status.

Anything would be good

Thanks

Tom

Edit:

```
function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null) {


    $request = new HttpRequest($url, HttpRequest::METH_POST);
     $request->setBody($data);
  $response = $request->send();
  return $response->getBody();

}


echo "before";

$response = do_post_request($url, $data);
echo "After";
```

Doing that makes "before" appear on the page. But no "After".

After managing to turn error reporting on I get this:

`Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found in /home/sites/ollysmithwineapp.com/public_html/mellowpages/geocode.php on line 25`

So I need another way to do the HTTP Request.

Comment: Curl would work, but make sure first by looking what the problem actually is. Set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to see errors

Comment: that doesn't work for some reason... still just a blank page...

Comment: A blank page may indicate that error display is off. Check your `php.ini` file for that option and set it to on.

Comment: ini_set('display_errors',1); // Enable error display

Comment: 400 is malformed syntax. Are u sure the URL you're using is valid?

Comment: Just as I thought: `Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found in /home/sites/........com/public_html/mellowpages/geocode.php on line 25` so... how else could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure HTTP extension is installed and configured correctly?

> ### Installation/Configuration
>
> **Installation**
>
> This » PECL extension is not bundled
>   with PHP.
>
> Information for installing this PECL
>   extension may be found in the manual
>   chapter titled Installation of PECL
>   extensions. Additional information
>   such as new releases, downloads,
>   source files, maintainer information,
>   and a CHANGELOG, can be located here:
>   »
>   http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http.

and maybe cURl is the way to go

- [RAW POST using cURL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871431/raw-post-using-curl-in-php)
- [PHP4: Send XML over HTTPS/POST via cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238784/php4-send-xml-over-https-post-via-curl)

Comment: that second link did it. :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Stolen from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code). You can insert `$data` directly where `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is set in place of the query string.

```
<?php
//
// A very simple PHP example that sends a HTTP POST to a remote site
//

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.mysite.com/tester.phtml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

// further processing ....
if ($server_output == "OK") { ... } else { ... }

?>
```

Comment: and that can take an XML string?

Comment: @Thomas take how? What do you mean?

Comment: basically $data is the contents of an XML file, I'm assuming it can, and I'm trying this. :)

Comment: @Thomas you can, just make sure you add a field name (unless you're parsing the raw POST request on the receiving end).

Comment: thanks a lot pekka :) the answer came from the link in @maggie's answer, however you were a great help, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I also found a solution using stream_context_create(). It gives you more control over what you're sending in the POST.

Here's a blog post explaining how to do it. It lets you easily specify the exact headers and body.

http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/

Answer (score 0):

There is no `HttpRequest::setBody()` method.  You should use the `addPostFields` function instead, using an associative array:

```
function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null) {
    $request = new HttpRequest($url, HttpRequest::METH_POST);
    $request->setPostFields($data);
    $response = $request->send();
    return $response->getBody();
}

$responseBody = do_post_request('http://www.example.com',array('examplefield'=>'exampledata'));
```

Comment: I need to send the contents of the $data variable (which at the moment is the contents of an XML document). How would I do this?